# What to log for torrent behavioral analysis

Tags: networking, router, logging, bittorrent

I would like to know exactly who to blame, when an email with copyright  infringement comes. I found several answers and information about it such as here: http://www.brighthub.com/computing/smb-security/articles/48875.aspx, and I liked the behavioral analysis aproach.

There is written that I should watch a single IP sending a lot of UDP packets to many different IPs, which I find an effective way to suspect somebody, because in the infringement email, there's time and date specified.

I have set up syslog server and the question is what exactly to log, I have mikrotik RB750 router, which offers these things to log:

> topics (info | critical | firewall | keepalive | packet | read | timer | write | ddns | hotspot | l2tp | ppp | route | update | account | debug | ike | manager | pppoe | script | warning | async | dhcp | info | notification | pptp | state | watchdog | bgp | error | ipsec | open | radius | system | web-proxy | calc | event | isdn | ospf | raw | telephony | wireless; default: info) - specifies log group or log message type

I tried logging `dns` and `packet` yet and the messages didn't contain IP address of the local network users, nor the protocol(UDP as stated in the article).

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an always on machine on that network? Your RB is pretty feature full but Wireshark will probably be simpler to match packet patterns. You'll see tracker announces(always in the clear even if torrent encryption is on) and once you know what trackers to look for can just log all requests sent to then.

Comment: Yes, there is a server running OS X, but how can I run Wireshark while not logged in as a user? The server has more users, so when we don't configure anything, the server is running without a user logged.

Comment: You could leave a permanently logged in account while others still use it.